# Открытие модального окна при закрытии сайта

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Как вывести модальное окно перед закрытием сайта, пробовал переделать вот такой скрипт:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (){
  if(confirm('Да неужели?')){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Получилось вот так:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (){
    $('#myModal').show()
}
```

Но всё равно не работает, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот вопрос уже не первый раз появляется тут, и не первый раз ответ один и тот-же. Современные браузеры, если и обрабатывают событие `onbeforeunload`, то никаких `модалок`, `ajax` запросов и т.д. вы не сможете совершить. Все что в вашей силе, это вывести текст в `системном модальном окне`. Все, больше ничего.

[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Ф-ция должна возвращать текст, который появится в модальном окне, изменить окно вы никак не можете.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "Ваше текст" }
```

Да и то, работает не всегда и не одинаоково